# How to paginate Firestore data in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

so I have been working on a web app similar to Instagram and I am trying to paginate the data(posts) from firestore, I tried the below code but on calling the function `loadMorePosts` it shows only the next two `posts` without retaining the previous new posts

Question 1: **Why doesn't it retain the previous new posts while setting the post in function `loadMorePosts`?**
I tried applying spread operator but it doesn't help so

```
setPosts(...posts,
          snapShot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, post: doc.data() }))
        );
```

Question 2: **Why `snapShot.docs[snapShot.docs.length - 1]` is an object, shouldn't it be a number?**

Question 3: **How to know that there are no more post to fetch?**

> ***Code :***

```
 const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
 const [latestDoc, setLatestDoc] = useState(null);

  const test = [];
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsub = db
      .collection("posts")
      .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
      .limit(2)
      .onSnapshot((snapShot) => {
        setPosts(
          snapShot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, post: doc.data() }))
        );

    setLatestDoc(snapShot.docs[snapShot.docs.length - 1]);
      });

    return unsub;
  }, []);

  const loadMorePosts = async () => {
    db.collection("posts")
      .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
      .startAfter(latestDoc)
      .limit(2)
      .onSnapshot((snapShot) => {
        setPosts(
          snapShot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, post: doc.data() }))
        );
        setLatestDoc(snapShot.docs[snapShot.docs.length - 1]);
      });
    console.log(test);
    console.log(latestDoc);
  };
```

Comment: Firestore pagination works based on cursor queries and knowing a so-called anchor object, not on numeric offsets as you seem to be used to . For a full explanation of Firestore's pagination model, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: Why doesn't it retain the previous new posts while setting the post in function loadMorePosts?
Because post is an array, use have to do this:

```
setPosts([...posts,
      ...snapShot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, post: doc.data() }))
    ]);
```

Question 2: Why snapShot.docs[snapShot.docs.length - 1] is an object, shouldn't it be a number? 
It is obviously an object, how can it be a number? 
It like:

```
snapShot.docs = [ {object 1}, {object 2}, {object 3} ]
snapShot.docs[snapShot.docs.length - 1] = snapShot.docs[2] = {object 3}
```

Question 3: How to know that there are no more post to fetch?

You could do something like this:

```
const [ hasMore, setHasMore ] = useState(false);
setHasMore(snapShot.docs.length > 0);
```

Comment: Hey, I tried your solution but there is a problem, the array set as `posts[{prevData},{prevData},[{newData},{Data}]]`, since we are using the map it returns an array of objects inside an array of objects, so do you know how to solve this problem

Comment: posts = [{prevData},{prevData},[{newData},{Data}]]

Comment: You can use spread at the map function to spread array of objects to objects. setPosts([...posts,
      ...snapShot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, post: doc.data() }))
    ]);

Comment: Hey your solution works, but when we add new  `posts`, it goes showing only  the top 2 posts from whatever number of posts you are seeing

Comment: can you help please!!

Comment: Can you post relevant code, did you use hasMore, how did you use it?

Comment: i am using the same code as above - (after getting the data i map through it and show the details of each post), i just add a button and on the onClick event, it calls the function  `loadMorePosts`

Comment: So the code work, but when you add new posts (I assumed more than 2), you call the function and it returns 2 posts (because you limit by 2 posts), you call again and it does not return any more posts? Is that right?

Comment: well that's not what I am not about , I am saying that initially my app loads only 2 posts as I added `limit to 2`t  then when I load all the posts(by clicking the `load more post` button) and add a new post then automatically it goes back displaying the recently added new post and the post after that(i.e. only 2 posts), like in the initial

Comment: Your loadMorePosts also limit to 2. When you load new post, did the previous post disappear? You should post the code so I can spot the problem.

Comment: Yeah that also limited to 2post only, well when I post a new post the loaded post disappear and only show 2 posts, Here's the link of the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-khorana-0txtz?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Isn't it expected behavior? Just like on Facebook, when you refresh the page, it'll show the most recent post? In your case, when you post a new post, the page reloads so the state is reset, the useEffect runs again. I don't know how you post a new post so you can use localStorage to save the state, or using AJAX to prevent reloading the page. Or if you want more posts loaded when posting a new post, just increase the limit in the useEffect.

Comment: How can it reload cause only rerenders in react, I think when it detects a new post (`onSnapshot`) it again runs the useEffect and since it has a limit, it sets only 2 posts like in the beginning

Comment: Your useEffect don't have any dependency (empty [] ) so it will only run once when the component get mounted. Check your post new posts function to see if it cause the page to refresh or not.

Comment: no `onSnapshot` listens for any realtime changes so it might rerender it

Comment: Indeed, so knowing the cause, it's will be an easy fix, isn't it?